# Detection Index or Position between of 2 list data with a distance

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I have 2 of list data

```
CurveA = {{140.796, 31.3888}, {140.555, 31.5343}, {140.314, 31.6829},  
 {140.076, 31.8344}, {139.839, 31.9889}, {139.604, 32.1464},
 {139.37, 32.3069}, {139.138, 32.4704}, {138.908, 32.6369}, 
 {138.68, 32.8065}, {138.452, 32.9791}, {138.227, 33.1547},  
 {138.003, 33.3334}, {137.781, 33.5152}, {137.56, 33.7}, 
 {137.341, 33.8879}, {137.123, 34.0789}, {136.907, 34.2729},
 {136.692, 34.4701}, {136.479, 34.6704}, {136.267, 34.8738}, {136.057, 35.0804}};

CurveB = {{140.492, 31.5563}, {139.939, 31.8567}, {139.38, 32.1475}, 
 {138.816, 32.4285}, {138.248, 32.6996}, {137.675, 32.9607}, 
 {137.098, 33.2118}, {136.516, 33.4528}};
```

If I want to know the index or position of a pairs data (`CurveA` and `CurveB`) which have distance of 1 mm, how to do that? Here is the illustration:

[image]

Comment: DistanceMatrix[]?

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to interpolate to find functions that represent the data and then find a root of that function. cA is the interpolation of CurveA, cB is the interpolation of CurveB, and you are looking for the value at which they are 1 apart:

```
cA = Interpolation[CurveA];
cB = Interpolation[CurveB]; 
FindRoot[cA[t] - cB[t] == 1, {t, 136}]
{t -> 136.868}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
iFA = Interpolation[CurveA];
iFB = Interpolation[CurveB];
Quiet @ ListPlot[{CurveA, CurveB, CurveA, CurveB},  
  Joined -> {True, True, False, False}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}, 
  BaseStyle -> PointSize[.02], 
  MeshStyle -> ({Red, Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}], Arrow@@#}&), 
  MeshFunctions -> {iFA[#] - iFB[#] &}, Mesh -> {{1}}]
```

[image]

Update: The `MeshStyle` trick above does not work with `ListLinePlot` in version 11.2. It does work with `Plot`, so, in version 11.2, you  can do

```
Quiet@Plot[{iFA[t],iFB[t]}, {t, 156, 141},
  MeshStyle -> ({Red, Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}], Arrow @@ #} &),
  MeshFunctions -> {iFA[#] - iFB[#] &}, Mesh -> {{1}}, 
  Epilog-> {ListPlot[{CurveA, CurveB}, PlotTheme -> "OpenMarkers"][[1]]}]
```

[image]